# Return PLS-00306 During login in with python

Tags: python, html, sql, asp.net

I am working on a crawler using Python to grab some data on company internal web.but when I posted all the data,it showed PLS-00306 wrong number or type of arguments in call to PM_USER_LOGIN_SP 
ORA-066550:line 1, column 7
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
I checked my Firefox inspector again and again, and all my request data were right, even I removed some of my request data or changed it, it returned another error code.
Is there someone help me out what's the problem.

Comment: sounds like a database error in the application you're making the request to

Answer (score 0):

Oracle procedure `PM_USER_LOGIN_SP` has one or more parameters, each of them having its own data type. When calling that procedure, you must match number and data type of each of them.

For example, if it expects 3 parameters, you can't pass only 2 (nor 4) of them (because of *wrong number* of arguments (parameters)).

If parameter #1 is `DATE`, you can't pass letter A to it (because of a *wrong type*). Note that  `DATEs` are kind of "special", because something that looks like a date to us, humans (such as 20.01.2018, which is today) passed to Oracle procedure's `DATE` data type parameter must really be a date. '20.01.2018' is a *string*, so either pass date literal, such as `DATE '2018-01-20'` or use appropriate function with a format mask, `TO_DATE('20.01.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy')`.

Therefore, have a look at the procedure first, pay attention to what it expects. Then check what you pass to it.

Comment: Thanks, there is no date in my post parameters,the five are __VIEWSTATE,__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR,__EVENTVALIDATION,and the remaining2 are the x&y coordinates of login button. I still don't know how to fix this issue,the workaround right now I used is selenium, but I really don't like it

Comment: "Date" was just for an example. So, did you check all 5 parameters & their data types on both sides: side A - what you pass. Side B - what Oracle expects?